# How to extract json key having colon in karate

Tags: karate

The response looks like:

```
{
    "result": "SUCCESS",

    "_links": {
        "payment:cancel": {
            "href": "http://myhost:8080/12345"
        }

    }
}
```

I tried with below:

```
* def value = Response._links.payment:cancel.href
```

Please help how to get value of "**payment:cancel**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def response = 
"""
{
    "result": "SUCCESS",

    "_links": {
        "payment:cancel": {
            "href": "http://myhost:8080/12345"
        }

    }
}
"""
* def value = response._links['payment:cancel'].href
* match value == 'http://myhost:8080/12345'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterThomas for quick response. It worked for me.